# Gitlab CI - Cache before_script tasks for docker container

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci.yml

I'm running an automated build in a Gitlab CI pipeline which is using an ubuntu container.
Before the actual build process I have to install and configure a lot of software. This takes veeery long compared to the build process itself.

My question now is: Cany I somehow cache the before_script setup tasks somehow so that they don't have to run every time?

```
stages:
  - build

image: ubuntu:jammy
variables:
  DISPLAY: ":0.0"

build_executable:
  stage: build
  before_script:
    # install and configure a lot of software, etc. This part takes very long. Can I cache those steps somehow?
  script:
    # An actually pretty short build process is happening here
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - dist/
  tags:
    - docker-runner
```

Comment: Instead of before_scriipt have you tried building the image FROM your current image, then use the build image?

Comment: @hakre What exactly do you mean? I don't have a container registry available in Gitlab and cannot push the build environment to a public container registry.

Comment: On the jobs you can only cache files or directories, if you are generating any of those on your `before_script` step then that will work for you. Otherwise it won't because you can't cache a set of tasks

Comment: @slarag: this explains it then, not an option for you, I was under the wrong impression that in Gitlab a Docker image/container registry is available as this if often the case. Try to workaround then with cache as [bhito](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11641073/bhito) [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76317189/gitlab-ci-cache-before-script-tasks-for-docker-container?noredirect=1#comment134585088_76317189).

Comment: Can you show what your actual install steps are or describe what software you are installing and how you are installing it? That may help us understand what exactly is taking a long time (is it downloading that's slow? Maybe you're compiling software from source that takes a long time?) and help us determine what options you have for speeding this up.

Comment: I've been talkin to our Gitlab Admin team and they will enable the container registry. :) I'm building executables from Python scripts using Pyinstaller. As I need them also for Windows (but don't have a Windows Runner available), I'm using Wine inside the container and install Python under Wine. This is the most time consuming part. For now I have just pushed an image to Docker Hub where Wine + Python under Wine are installed. As soon as the Gitlab Container registry is available I will create the final build container there. Thank you very much for you support!